# jQuery Ajax Post - Print the data you just posted in the callback

Tags: jquery, post

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({        
            url: "some-page.aspx",
            type: "POST",
            data: {fileName: file, param02: param02, param03: param03, param05: param05, param08: param08, param11: param11},

            success: function(html){            
                // check the table to see if the document made it

            },
            error: function(html){
            }           
    });
```

My desire is to print the data I just posted. I know that jquery figures out on its own how to encode the posted parameters and I would like to see how they are actually posted. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the tools provided by Google Chrome. Open them by hitting F12 while in chrome, and go to the "network" Tab. There you will see all data going back and forth during the ajax call.
Or you could also use firebug which is a Firefox plugin. Once installed, hit F12 while in Firefox and go to the "Console" tab. Once you make the ajax call, you will see it show up in the console and once you expand it, you can see all the data going back and forth during the ajax call.
Or you can also use the tools provided by internet explorer (IE 8 and up). In IE hit F12 to open up the tools window and go to the "Network" tab. Click on the "Start capturing" button. Perform the ajax call in the page and you should see it show up in the "Network" tab. You can now click on it and click on the "Go to detail view" to view all the data related to the ajax call.

Comment: Command + alt + I for OS X systems (and Safari also has one dev tool really good)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
success:function(data_response){
    alert(data_response);
}
```

make sure the data is in string format.

You could also try using a get function instead

```
$.get('/path/to/url', 
    function(data_response){
           alert(data_response);
    });
```

source: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=156453

Comment: The question says "I want to print the data **I POSTed** ". You are printing the response.

Answer (score 1):

In the success, use console.log on this.data

```
$.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/script.php",
        data: { "var1" : var1, "var2" : var2 },
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function( html ) {
            console.log(this.data);
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're meaning you want to see what was sent to the server you can use a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (if you're on Windows) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) (cross-platform but not free).

Both of these tools act as proxy servers and intercept the data that has been sent to the server so you can inspect it, both of these will show you exactly what was submitted to the server.